# Define timeframe for animation in KML

Tags: animation, kml

Is there any possibility to define a timewindow for an animation of KML objects? Like if i have to occurences animated (polygon 1 appears on the 1/1/2018 and polygon 2 on the 6/10/2018). Is there any way to define that the whole animation should last for f.e. 30 or 45 seconds? I only see that Google Earth always interpolates the animation time depending on the given

```html
<TimeSpan> <begin> 2004-03 </begin> <end>2004-04</end></TimeSpan>
```

dates of the document.

Answer (score 0):

In the current Google Earth Pro interface, there is no way to specify the duration (in playback-time) of an animation like this.  As you noted, it expands the time slider to include the dates & times from all loaded KMLs, and plays across the slider at a preset speed (adjustable in the slider settings).

One way you could apply time playback with precise control is to set up a KML Tour which animates between two views (with time tags applied), over a specific number of seconds.  Then you could have your user play it back using the Tour interface instead, and see the timing you want.  Unfortunately KML Touring is rather complex with a long learning curve. There are simple things you can do (possibly including something like your request) using the tour recording interfaces in Earth Pro, but to really harness the full power of touring you'll need to create custom KML code, so consider yourself warned.  :-)